# org.springframework#spring-test;latest.release: not found when installing grails mail plugin

Tags: email, grails-plugin, dependency-management

I am getting dependency issues when installing the grails mail plugin (grails install-plugin mail). I have also posted this issue in the grails user mailing list as a reply @ the following link: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Installing-quot-mail-quot-plugin-fails-td3245058.html

My setup is as follows:
Grails app version: 1.3.7
IDE: IntelliJ
lib: mail.jar, activation-1.1.jar
BuildConfig.groovy:  grailsPlugins()
                     grailsHome()
                     grailsCentral()
                     //mavenCentral()
When I install the mail plugin I get the following message

```
    **:: org.springframework#spring-test;latest.release: not found**
```

What I have tried (All these were suggestion on the link provided above):

1. Put a runtime dependency as follows (still did not install the plugin):
           **runtime  "org.springframework:spring-test:3.0.+"**
2. Exclude the dependency, still no luck at getting the plugin installed.
       **runtime( ':mail:1.0-SNAPSHOT' ) {
          excludes "spring-test"
       }**
3. **Uncommented mavenCentral()**. This got the plugin installed correctly, but it did not show up in IntelliJ under the Plugins section with all the other plugins I am using. So when I was trying to use the Mail plugin either from a controller or from a service like Marc Palmer suggests in the following link the classes were not found: http://s3.amazonaws.com/AnyWare/Blog/Screencasts/Grails%20Rocks%20Screencast%20%231%20-%20Grails%20Mail.mov

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
- Dario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found my own answer again. Basically, **it came down to restart intellij** and the plugin will show under plugins. For some reason while doing "Grails/Synchronize Grails Settings" was not making the plugin show up.

So to successfully install the gails mail plugin do as follows

1. Add **activation1-1.jar** and **mail.jar** to your lib folder
2. In **BuildConfig.groovy** uncomment mavenCenral()
3. Run grails command: **grails install-plugin mail**
4. In IntelliJ click on **Apply Grails Changes to IDEA project structure** if asked in the
   yellow popup
5. If IntelliJ still does not recognize the plugin do **Grails/Synchronize Grails** either 
   by right clicking on "Plugins" or in the project name
6. If IntelliJ still does not recognize the plugin, restart IntelliJ do a **Grails/Synchronize Grails**.
7. The plugin should be correctly installed and ready to use.

Comment: how can we find activation1-1.jar and mail.jar? I found A lot of. which will be fix it

Comment: If you go to findjar.com and type activation-1.1.jar and mail.jar you should find them there. Also if you download the Java EE SDK from Oracle which comes with Glassfish App Server you should find them there as well under the glassfish/lib folder.